# Internet traffic when connected to a SonicWALL VPN

Tags: vpn, internet, sonicwall

We have a new VPN to let all users connect to the company's applications through it (inside the company net).

We have a lot of users using the SonicWALL Client and we want to allow them use Internet.

The problem is that we don't want them to use the VPN for this traffic (I mean they should go out to Internet throught their own Internet provider at home).

I supose this is a client configuration but I can't realize what it is... Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3):

On the Sonicwall router, browse to VPN and edit the "Group VPN" policy.   You want to make sure that "Allow Connections to:" is set to "Split Tunnels" and that the "Default Gateway" box is unchecked:

[image: Sonicwall VPN configuration page]

Comment: That's already done :-( Thanks for your answer ;-).

Any other idea?

Comment: That answer is pretty much it. It's how I have configured it and it prevents users from using the VPN connection by default for their internet browsing. If you really want you can create some custom firewall rules to disallow traffic, but afaik sonicwall takes care of that on its own already.

Comment: Can't realize what's happening. This rule means every connection will "try" it throught the VPN and, after that, it will connect throught the user's Internet provider??

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as zapico. I already changed "Allow connections to" to "Split tunnels" and disabled "Set default route as this gateway", but the SonicWALL VPN client still used the VPN connection as the default gateway.

After some trying I found out that it depends on the "VPN Client Access Networks" configured in User -> Local users -> Edit user -> VPN access. I just chose one internal network and it worked fine.

Internal network traffic goes through VPN and all internet traffic uses the internet connection.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using camouflageX's answer and my suspicions that user config was at fault, I just removed all previous settings for the users and allowed "All MGMT IP". All works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the configuration -

1) Virtual Adapter settings (allow connection to split tunnels)

2) not-tick the set default route as this gateway

3) "VPN Client Access Networks" configured in User -> Local users -> Edit user -> VPN access. Basically set only X0 subnet as the allowed address in the VPN assigned local user group

my outgoing WAN connection after establishing an L2TP connection persists to utilize the WAN IP of my remote network.

I had to configure the dial-up connection properties, IPv4 settings, and untick the set default route on remote gateway, to allow route of traffic via local internet.

Previously, without the above configuration, removing the tick on the setting for allow route will cause the VPN connection to not be established. However, the settings above (1,2,3) seems to have allowed me to disable the default route.

Comment: it seems that if i configure on the client configuration, should the client network exists in the same subnet range as the office network, the configuration will break and the routing will not take place. Sigh...